# Words to describe boredom without sounding negative

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I work as a developer and currently in my department, we do not have any projects going on. Therefore my supervisor asked me to do some training on X. I personally like learning X. However I have been learning X for about few weeks and I started to feel bored and sick of X. I want to tell my supervisor about it and then change my training subject to Y, or Z, etc.

Basically, what I want to say is:

> I am bored learning X for so long. Can I learn something else like Y or Z?

Of course, 'bored' looks really negative in a work environment, but I could not find better words for it.

I found these words but it looks negative as well:

> fed up, tired, weary, exhausted, have had enough

What words can I use to describe 'bored' without sounding so negative?

Comment: After having spent a few weeks on X, I feel that Y or Z is more interesting to me. Could you please switch me to that?

Comment: @MaulikV Thank you Maulik, that's a nice phrase suggestion. but I am actually looking for word(s) :) 

I have edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: You could say *something is "***not challenging***", or that you would like something "***more challenging***".

Comment: If the problem really is just that you've been doing the same thing for too long, you can say something like "I'm feeling a little **burnt out** working exclusively on X.  Can I do some Y/Z for variety?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can describe yourself as being ***burned out*** (also "burnt out"), or suffering from ***[burnout](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burnout)***:

> the condition of someone who has become very physically and emotionally tired after doing a difficult job for a long time
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burnout)*</sub>

To express your feeling and desire for something new to do, you might say something like "I'm feeling a little burnt out working exclusively on X. Can I do some Y/Z for a change of pace?"

Answer (score 1):

Boredom is inherently seen as negative. It sounds like what you are asking is not how to express your boredom but how to request doing something different *without* expressing that boredom. In that case, you might consider:

> I need a break from this subject.

or...

> I think I've reached my limit on this subject for a while.

...or both.

Comment: I like this answer too, but in this case, I'm looking for words to describe what I feel (boredom). So I decided to choose Hellion's answer.

Answer (score 0):

To put a positive spin on this, to use euphemism and a touch of irony if you like, you could divert attention from boredom to saying that you have **satisfied** or **satiated your curiosity** learning X.

> **satiate**
>
> verb [ T often passive ] FORMAL
>
> to completely satisfy yourself or a need, especially with food or pleasure, so that you could not have any more:
>
> *'In locations that have inherent dangers and would not normally be accessible to the public, viewing areas provide a way to **satiate** the public curiosity without exposing inordinate risk.'*
>
> [satiate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/satiate) in Cambridge English Dictionary.
>
> *'he folded up his newspaper, his curiosity **satiated**'*
>
> *'Her curiosity **satiated**, she walked away without a backwards glance.'*
>
> *'Her curiosity was soon **satiated** when the door opened to reveal a handsome young man of about twenty with bright red hair and the palest blue eyes she had ever seen.'*
>
> [satiate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/satiate) in Oxford Living Dictionaries.

**To satisfy** (in combination with the same **curiosity**) is a more pedestrian synonym.

> *'Come on, **satisfy** my curiosity (= tell me what I want to know) - what happened last night?'*
>
> [satisfy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/satisfy) in Cambridge English Dictionary.

Comment: I understand your idea of using euphemism. However I do not think this is the best fit for my circumstances (work environment). Thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In the theory of learning there's the concept of "varied practice". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varied_practice) describes this as:

> *the use of a training schedule that includes frequent changes of task so that the performer is constantly confronting novel instantiations of the to-be-learned information*.

As mentioned in the Wikipedia article under ['Theory'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varied_practice#Theory), you could say that you'd benefit from **contextual interference**:

> *Contextual interference refers to a learning benefit observed when the items to be learned are randomly intermixed across training blocks rather than repeated in blocks*

Comment: While I think this is a useful and informative answer, I think it's also worth noting that many (if not most) native speakers won't be familiar with the terms _varied practice_ or _contextual interference_.

Comment: Completely agreed @J.R. and thanks for the useful and clarifying editing!